# Is a valid kernel function have to be positive definite?

Tags: machine-learning, kernel-trick

Positive semi-definite(PSD) kernels confuse me a lot. Are PSD kernels valid kernels? I used to read some papers in which the authors define PSD kernels and use them for some tasks. However, I think a valid kernel should be positive-definite.

Comment: PSD stands for positive semidefinite?

Comment: @carlo Yes, I have read some papers in which the authors define a PSD kernel function and use it for some tasks.